# Getting State From Google Location Service

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to show the users:

```
Los Angeles, CA

[City],[State Abriviation]
```

android.location.Address has mLocality='Los Angeles'
                                 mAdminArea='California'

Now I notice that there is also `mSubLocality`? and `mSubAdminArea`?

I am restricting this to searching the US.   But I still need to be sure that state always appears as `mAdminArea`.  Also I would prefer that it was returned as the state code like AL, AZ, CA etc.  I can use a utility to convert these however I would prefer to get the code back. A code is used for the county.  Anyway is there any circumstance where I would see a `mSubAdminArea` in the US?  or any case where the State would not appear in mAdminArea?  This app is going out to a lot of folks so I really need confirmation on this issue.  I realize `mAdminArea` can be null which is ok, but if there is a state returned will it always appear under `mAdminArea` and not `mSubAdminArea` or somewhere else. Is there anyway to get the abbreviation instead of the whole state name?

If not please answer this question: [Is there a Util to convert US State Name to State Code. eg. Arizona to AZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005751/is-there-a-util-to-convert-us-state-name-to-state-code-eg-arizona-to-az)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getAddressLine(index)` to retrieve all the parts of the address one of its parts will have `City`, `State Abriviation`.