# Is there a Util to convert US State Name to State Code. eg. Arizona to AZ?

Tags: java, android

I need to convert full state name to its official state address code.  For example from the String New York, I need to produce NY.  Now I could put this all in a hashmap, but it seems there must be a utility for this? I am in an Android environment.  I don't want to import a large library just for this one util however. Thanks

Comment: you need to add only one map to hold this information as Óscar López suggests, not a big overhead

Comment: There is value to the question because it could have existed in a common library of some sort, but we now have a community opinion that it does not, and a validated answer using a HashMap correctly parametized, that would need to be re-tested if every one entered it separately.  Beginning programmers would also not necessarily be aware of the the use of HashMaps in this manner exp. because of the separation of characters.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I have it ready-made - you can use it:

```
Map<String, String> states = new HashMap<String, String>();
states.put("Alabama","AL");
states.put("Alaska","AK");
states.put("Alberta","AB");
states.put("American Samoa","AS");
states.put("Arizona","AZ");
states.put("Arkansas","AR");
states.put("Armed Forces (AE)","AE");
states.put("Armed Forces Americas","AA");
states.put("Armed Forces Pacific","AP");
states.put("British Columbia","BC");
states.put("California","CA");
states.put("Colorado","CO");
states.put("Connecticut","CT");
states.put("Delaware","DE");
states.put("District Of Columbia","DC");
states.put("Florida","FL");
states.put("Georgia","GA");
states.put("Guam","GU");
states.put("Hawaii","HI");
states.put("Idaho","ID");
states.put("Illinois","IL");
states.put("Indiana","IN");
states.put("Iowa","IA");
states.put("Kansas","KS");
states.put("Kentucky","KY");
states.put("Louisiana","LA");
states.put("Maine","ME");
states.put("Manitoba","MB");
states.put("Maryland","MD");
states.put("Massachusetts","MA");
states.put("Michigan","MI");
states.put("Minnesota","MN");
states.put("Mississippi","MS");
states.put("Missouri","MO");
states.put("Montana","MT");
states.put("Nebraska","NE");
states.put("Nevada","NV");
states.put("New Brunswick","NB");
states.put("New Hampshire","NH");
states.put("New Jersey","NJ");
states.put("New Mexico","NM");
states.put("New York","NY");
states.put("Newfoundland","NF");
states.put("North Carolina","NC");
states.put("North Dakota","ND");
states.put("Northwest Territories","NT");
states.put("Nova Scotia","NS");
states.put("Nunavut","NU");
states.put("Ohio","OH");
states.put("Oklahoma","OK");
states.put("Ontario","ON");
states.put("Oregon","OR");
states.put("Pennsylvania","PA");
states.put("Prince Edward Island","PE");
states.put("Puerto Rico","PR");
states.put("Quebec","QC");
states.put("Rhode Island","RI");
states.put("Saskatchewan","SK");
states.put("South Carolina","SC");
states.put("South Dakota","SD");
states.put("Tennessee","TN");
states.put("Texas","TX");
states.put("Utah","UT");
states.put("Vermont","VT");
states.put("Virgin Islands","VI");
states.put("Virginia","VA");
states.put("Washington","WA");
states.put("West Virginia","WV");
states.put("Wisconsin","WI");
states.put("Wyoming","WY");
states.put("Yukon Territory","YT");
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 100 times for the amount of typing you just saved me. I recommend changing HashMap to LinkedHashMap to maintain the alphabetical order.

Comment: I guess my previous comment of maintaining sort order doesn't make much sense from the perspective of the original question. I wanted this list to populate a UI drop-down though.

Comment: You've added some Canadian states too. The OP is asking for the US state names.

Comment: @Hamdi true, I forgot I had Canada's provinces there as well. you can ignore it (won't change the functionality from the OP perspective - unless you have similar requirements to Mark B). Otherwise, just go over [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provinces_and_territories_of_Canada#Provinces) and remove these 11 provinces.

Comment: even better would be to use an Enum

Comment: @atom88 better in what sense ?

Comment: @alfasin, you get all the benefits of enums, such as "Compile time checking" instead of "run time checking"  So, if you had an error it's better to catch it BEFORE you roll it out to your customers / production environment.

Answer (score 37):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but just in case someone needs the opposite: to use state/province abbreviations as keys and names as values. It took me a few minutes to reformat the map. Also, the abbreviation for Quebec in the accepted answer is wrong.

```
public static final Map<String, String> STATE_MAP;
static {
    STATE_MAP = new HashMap<String, String>();
    STATE_MAP.put("AL", "Alabama");
    STATE_MAP.put("AK", "Alaska");
    STATE_MAP.put("AB", "Alberta");
    STATE_MAP.put("AZ", "Arizona");
    STATE_MAP.put("AR", "Arkansas");
    STATE_MAP.put("BC", "British Columbia");
    STATE_MAP.put("CA", "California");
    STATE_MAP.put("CO", "Colorado");
    STATE_MAP.put("CT", "Connecticut");
    STATE_MAP.put("DE", "Delaware");
    STATE_MAP.put("DC", "District Of Columbia");
    STATE_MAP.put("FL", "Florida");
    STATE_MAP.put("GA", "Georgia");
    STATE_MAP.put("GU", "Guam");
    STATE_MAP.put("HI", "Hawaii");
    STATE_MAP.put("ID", "Idaho");
    STATE_MAP.put("IL", "Illinois");
    STATE_MAP.put("IN", "Indiana");
    STATE_MAP.put("IA", "Iowa");
    STATE_MAP.put("KS", "Kansas");
    STATE_MAP.put("KY", "Kentucky");
    STATE_MAP.put("LA", "Louisiana");
    STATE_MAP.put("ME", "Maine");
    STATE_MAP.put("MB", "Manitoba");
    STATE_MAP.put("MD", "Maryland");
    STATE_MAP.put("MA", "Massachusetts");
    STATE_MAP.put("MI", "Michigan");
    STATE_MAP.put("MN", "Minnesota");
    STATE_MAP.put("MS", "Mississippi");
    STATE_MAP.put("MO", "Missouri");
    STATE_MAP.put("MT", "Montana");
    STATE_MAP.put("NE", "Nebraska");
    STATE_MAP.put("NV", "Nevada");
    STATE_MAP.put("NB", "New Brunswick");
    STATE_MAP.put("NH", "New Hampshire");
    STATE_MAP.put("NJ", "New Jersey");
    STATE_MAP.put("NM", "New Mexico");
    STATE_MAP.put("NY", "New York");
    STATE_MAP.put("NF", "Newfoundland");
    STATE_MAP.put("NC", "North Carolina");
    STATE_MAP.put("ND", "North Dakota");
    STATE_MAP.put("NT", "Northwest Territories");
    STATE_MAP.put("NS", "Nova Scotia");
    STATE_MAP.put("NU", "Nunavut");
    STATE_MAP.put("OH", "Ohio");
    STATE_MAP.put("OK", "Oklahoma");
    STATE_MAP.put("ON", "Ontario");
    STATE_MAP.put("OR", "Oregon");
    STATE_MAP.put("PA", "Pennsylvania");
    STATE_MAP.put("PE", "Prince Edward Island");
    STATE_MAP.put("PR", "Puerto Rico");
    STATE_MAP.put("QC", "Quebec");
    STATE_MAP.put("RI", "Rhode Island");
    STATE_MAP.put("SK", "Saskatchewan");
    STATE_MAP.put("SC", "South Carolina");
    STATE_MAP.put("SD", "South Dakota");
    STATE_MAP.put("TN", "Tennessee");
    STATE_MAP.put("TX", "Texas");
    STATE_MAP.put("UT", "Utah");
    STATE_MAP.put("VT", "Vermont");
    STATE_MAP.put("VI", "Virgin Islands");
    STATE_MAP.put("VA", "Virginia");
    STATE_MAP.put("WA", "Washington");
    STATE_MAP.put("WV", "West Virginia");
    STATE_MAP.put("WI", "Wisconsin");
    STATE_MAP.put("WY", "Wyoming");
    STATE_MAP.put("YT", "Yukon Territory");
}
```

Comment: You too have added some Canadian states too. The OP is asking for the US state names.

Comment: I needed the Canadian states. Does not hurt to include them.

Comment: You guys should probably be working together on a shared library for this, however I commend the effort of continuing a post / thread in the name of accuracy, You get my vote.

Answer (score 9):

Even better to use an Enum.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum State {

    ALABAMA("Alabama", "AL"), ALASKA("Alaska", "AK"), AMERICAN_SAMOA("American Samoa", "AS"), ARIZONA("Arizona", "AZ"), ARKANSAS(
    "Arkansas", "AR"), CALIFORNIA("California", "CA"), COLORADO("Colorado", "CO"), CONNECTICUT("Connecticut", "CT"), DELAWARE(
    "Delaware", "DE"), DISTRICT_OF_COLUMBIA("District of Columbia", "DC"), FEDERATED_STATES_OF_MICRONESIA(
    "Federated States of Micronesia", "FM"), FLORIDA("Florida", "FL"), GEORGIA("Georgia", "GA"), GUAM("Guam", "GU"), HAWAII(
    "Hawaii", "HI"), IDAHO("Idaho", "ID"), ILLINOIS("Illinois", "IL"), INDIANA("Indiana", "IN"), IOWA("Iowa", "IA"), KANSAS(
    "Kansas", "KS"), KENTUCKY("Kentucky", "KY"), LOUISIANA("Louisiana", "LA"), MAINE("Maine", "ME"), MARYLAND("Maryland", "MD"), MARSHALL_ISLANDS(
    "Marshall Islands", "MH"), MASSACHUSETTS("Massachusetts", "MA"), MICHIGAN("Michigan", "MI"), MINNESOTA("Minnesota", "MN"), MISSISSIPPI(
    "Mississippi", "MS"), MISSOURI("Missouri", "MO"), MONTANA("Montana", "MT"), NEBRASKA("Nebraska", "NE"), NEVADA("Nevada",
    "NV"), NEW_HAMPSHIRE("New Hampshire", "NH"), NEW_JERSEY("New Jersey", "NJ"), NEW_MEXICO("New Mexico", "NM"), NEW_YORK(
    "New York", "NY"), NORTH_CAROLINA("North Carolina", "NC"), NORTH_DAKOTA("North Dakota", "ND"), NORTHERN_MARIANA_ISLANDS(
    "Northern Mariana Islands", "MP"), OHIO("Ohio", "OH"), OKLAHOMA("Oklahoma", "OK"), OREGON("Oregon", "OR"), PALAU("Palau",
    "PW"), PENNSYLVANIA("Pennsylvania", "PA"), PUERTO_RICO("Puerto Rico", "PR"), RHODE_ISLAND("Rhode Island", "RI"), SOUTH_CAROLINA(
    "South Carolina", "SC"), SOUTH_DAKOTA("South Dakota", "SD"), TENNESSEE("Tennessee", "TN"), TEXAS("Texas", "TX"), UTAH(
    "Utah", "UT"), VERMONT("Vermont", "VT"), VIRGIN_ISLANDS("Virgin Islands", "VI"), VIRGINIA("Virginia", "VA"), WASHINGTON(
    "Washington", "WA"), WEST_VIRGINIA("West Virginia", "WV"), WISCONSIN("Wisconsin", "WI"), WYOMING("Wyoming", "WY"), UNKNOWN(
    "Unknown", "");

    /**
     * The state's name.
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * The state's abbreviation.
     */
    private String abbreviation;

    /**
     * The set of states addressed by abbreviations.
     */
    private static final Map<String, State> STATES_BY_ABBR = new HashMap<String, State>();

    /* static initializer */
    static {
        for (State state : values()) {
            STATES_BY_ABBR.put(state.getAbbreviation(), state);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new state.
     *
     * @param name the state's name.
     * @param abbreviation the state's abbreviation.
     */
    State(String name, String abbreviation) {
        this.name = name;
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the state's abbreviation.
     *
     * @return the state's abbreviation.
     */
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the enum constant with the specified abbreviation.
     *
     * @param abbr the state's abbreviation.
     * @return the enum constant with the specified abbreviation.
     * @throws SunlightException if the abbreviation is invalid.
     */
    public static State valueOfAbbreviation(final String abbr) {
        final State state = STATES_BY_ABBR.get(abbr);
        if (state != null) {
            return state;
        } else {
            return UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    public static State valueOfName(final String name) {
        final String enumName = name.toUpperCase().replaceAll(" ", "_");
        try {
            return valueOf(enumName);
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return State.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for making this an enum vs the simple solution above?

Comment: An enum makes everything properly immutable. Other solutions that make a map `static final` do not protect the map from overwriting a state, deleting a state, or making up a new state.

Comment: you get all the benefits of enums, such as "Compile time checking" instead of "run time checking" So, if you had an error it's better to catch it BEFORE you roll it out to your customers / production environment

Answer (score 5):

This is the updated version with Codes for United States (US) and US Territories, Canada, and Mexico. This is a 2-way map. As such, this provides names for the given codes and vice-versa. Scroll down to see both options.

```
private static final Map<String, String> stateCodeToNameMap = new HashMap<>();

private static final Map<String, String> stateNameToCodeMap = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // Load US Codes.
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AK", "Alaska");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AL", "Alabama");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AR", "Arkansas");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AZ", "Arizona");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CA", "California");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CO", "Colorado");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CT", "Connecticut");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("DC", "District of Columbia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("DE", "Delaware");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("FL", "Florida");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("GA", "Georgia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("HI", "Hawaii");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("IA", "Iowa");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ID", "Idaho");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("IL", "Illinois");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("IN", "Indiana");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("KS", "Kansas");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("KY", "Kentucky");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("LA", "Louisiana");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MA", "Massachusetts");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MD", "Maryland");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ME", "Maine");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MI", "Michigan");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MN", "Minnesota");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MO", "Missouri");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MS", "Mississippi");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MT", "Montana");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NC", "North Carolina");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ND", "North Dakota");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NE", "Nebraska");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NH", "New Hampshire");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NJ", "New Jersey");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NM", "New Mexico");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NV", "Nevada");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NY", "New York");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("OH", "Ohio");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("OK", "Oklahoma");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("OR", "Oregon");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("PA", "Pennsylvania");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("RI", "Rhode Island");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SC", "South Carolina");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SD", "South Dakota");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("TN", "Tennessee");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("TX", "Texas");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("UT", "Utah");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("VA", "Virginia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("VT", "Vermont");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("WA", "Washington");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("WI", "Wisconsin");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("WV", "West Virginia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("WY", "Wyoming");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("GU", "Guam");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("VI", "Virgin Islands");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("PR", "Puerto Rico");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AE", "Armed forces - Europe");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AA", "Armed forces - America");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AP", "Armed forces - Pacific");

    // Load Canada Codes.
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AB", "Alberta");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("BC", "British Columbia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MB", "Manitoba");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NB", "New Brunswick");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NL", "Newfoundland and Labrador");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NT", "Northwest Territories");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NS", "Nova Scotia");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NU", "Nunavut");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ON", "Ontario");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("PE", "Prince Edward Island");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("QC", "Quebec");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SK", "Saskatchewan");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("YT", "Yukon");

    // Load México Codes.
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("AGU", "Aguascalientes");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("BCN", "Baja California");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("BCS", "Baja California Sur");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CAM", "Campeche");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CHP", "Chiapas");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("CHH", "Chihuahua");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("COA", "Coahuila");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("COL", "Colima");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("DIF", "Distrito Federal");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("DUR", "Durango");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("GUA", "Guanajuato");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("GRO", "Guerrero");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("HID", "Hidalgo");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("JAL", "Jalisco");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MEX", "México");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MIC", "Michoacán");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("MOR", "Morelos");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NAY", "Nayarit");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("NLE", "Nuevo León");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("OAX", "Oaxaca");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("PUE", "Puebla");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("QUE", "Querétaro");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ROO", "Quintana Roo");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SLP", "San Luis Potosí");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SIN", "Sinaloa");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("SON", "Sonora");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("TAB", "Tabasco");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("TAM", "Tamaulipas");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("TLA", "Tlaxcala");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("VER", "Veracruz");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("YUC", "Yucatán");
    stateCodeToNameMap.put("ZAC", "Zacatecas");


    // Load US State Names.
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Alabama","AL");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Alaska","AK");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Arizona","AZ");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Arkansas","AR");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("California","CA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Colorado","CO");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Connecticut","CT");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Delaware","DE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("District Of Columbia","DC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Florida","FL");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Georgia","GA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Hawaii","HI");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Idaho","ID");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Illinois","IL");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Indiana","IN");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Iowa","IA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Kansas","KS");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Kentucky","KY");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Louisiana","LA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Maine","ME");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Maryland","MD");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Massachusetts","MA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Michigan","MI");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Minnesota","MN");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Mississippi","MS");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Missouri","MO");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Montana","MT");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nebraska","NE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nevada","NV");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("New Hampshire","NH");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("New Jersey","NJ");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("New Mexico","NM");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("New York","NY");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("North Carolina","NC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("North Dakota","ND");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Ohio","OH");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Oklahoma","OK");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Oregon","OR");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Pennsylvania","PA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Rhode Island","RI");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("South Carolina","SC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("South Dakota","SD");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Tennessee","TN");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Texas","TX");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Utah","UT");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Vermont","VT");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Virginia","VA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Washington","WA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("West Virginia","WV");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Wisconsin","WI");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Wyoming","WY");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Guam", "GU");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Puerto Rico","PR");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Virgin Islands","VI");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Armed Forces (AE)","AE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Armed Forces Americas","AA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Armed Forces Pacific","AP");


    // Load Canada State Names.
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Alberta","AB");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("British Columbia","BC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Manitoba","MB");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("New Brunswick","NB");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Newfoundland and Labrador","NF");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Northwest Territories","NT");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nova Scotia","NS");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nunavut","NU");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Ontario","ON");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Prince Edward Island","PE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Quebec","QC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Saskatchewan","SK");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Yukon Territory","YT");


    // Load México State Names.
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Aguascalientes", "AGU");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Baja California", "BCN");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Baja California Sur", "BCS");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Campeche", "CAM");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Chiapas", "CHP");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Chihuahua", "CHH");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Coahuila", "COA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Colima", "COL");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Distrito Federal", "DIF");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Durango", "DUR");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Guanajuato", "GUA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Guerrero", "GRO");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Hidalgo", "HID");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Jalisco", "JAL");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("México", "MEX");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Michoacán", "MIC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Morelos", "MOR");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nayarit", "NAY");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Nuevo León", "NLE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Oaxaca", "OAX");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Puebla", "PUE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Querétaro", "QUE");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Quintana Roo", "ROO");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("San Luis Potosí", "SLP");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Sinaloa", "SIN");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Sonora", "SON");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Tabasco", "TAB");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Tamaulipas", "TAM");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Tlaxcala", "TLA");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Veracruz", "VER");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Yucatán", "YUC");
    stateNameToCodeMap.put("Zacatecas", "ZAC");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way would be with a HashMap. Even if there was a library to convert it, it would probably use the same thing.

```
Map<String, String> states = new HashMap<String, String>();
states.put("Arizona", "AZ");
states.put("California", "CA");
// So on and so forth...

// Then you could create a method like
public String toStateCode(String s) {
    return states.get(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As key and value:

```
public enum State {

    AK("AK", "Alaska"),
    AL("AL", "Alabama"),
    AR("AR", "Arkansas"),
    AZ("AZ", "Arizona"),
    CA("CA", "California"),
    CO("CO", "Colorado"),
    CT("CT", "Connecticut"),
    DE("DE", "Delaware"),
    FL("FL", "Florida"),
    GA("GA", "Georgia"),
    HI("HI", "Hawaii"),
    IA("IA", "Iowa"),
    ID("ID", "Idaho"),
    IL("IL", "Illinois"),
    IN("IN", "Indiana"),
    KS("KS", "Kansas"),
    KY("KY", "Kentucky"),
    LA("LA", "Louisiana"),
    MA("MA", "Massachusetts"),
    MD("MD", "Maryland"),
    ME("ME", "Maine"),
    MI("MI", "Michigan"),
    MN("MN", "Minnesota"),
    MO("MO", "Missouri"),
    MS("MS", "Mississippi"),
    MT("MT", "Montana"),
    NC("NC", "NorthCarolina"),
    ND("ND", "NorthDakota"),
    NE("NE", "Nebraska"),
    NH("NH", "NewHampshire"),
    NJ("NJ", "NewJersey"),
    NM("NM", "NewMexico"),
    NV("NV", "Nevada"),
    NY("NY", "NewYork"),
    OH("OH", "Ohio"),
    OK("OK", "Oklahoma"),
    OR("OR", "Oregon"),
    PA("PA", "Pennsylvania"),
    RI("RI", "RhodeIsland"),
    SC("SC", "SouthCarolina"),
    SD("SD", "SouthDakota"),
    TN("TN", "Tennessee"),
    TX("TX", "Texas"),
    UT("UT", "Utah"),
    VA("VA", "Virginia"),
    VT("VT", "Vermont"),
    WA("WA", "Washington"),
    WI("WI", "Wisconsin"),
    WV("WV", "WestVirginia"),
    WY("WY", "Wyoming");

    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    State(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the ENUM much better... you get all the benefits of enums, such as "Compile time checking" instead of "run time checking" So, if you had an error it's better to catch it BEFORE you roll it out to your customers / production environment

Answer (score 1):

Build a `Map<String, String>` with the codes and values, it's simple to do and with very little data. There's no "utility" for this, it's very specific for the application you're building.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so (At least I never heard of it). But you can always use a dictionary to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Kotlin code:

```
enum class State(val stateName: String) {
    AK("Alaska"),
    AL("Alabama"),
    AR("Arkansas"),
    AZ("Arizona"),
    CA("California"),
    CO("Colorado"),
    CT("Connecticut"),
    DE("Delaware"),
    FL("Florida"),
    GA("Georgia"),
    HI("Hawaii"),
    IA("Iowa"),
    ID("Idaho"),
    IL("Illinois"),
    IN("Indiana"),
    KS("Kansas"),
    KY("Kentucky"),
    LA("Louisiana"),
    MA("Massachusetts"),
    MD("Maryland"),
    ME("Maine"),
    MI("Michigan"),
    MN("Minnesota"),
    MO("Missouri"),
    MS("Mississippi"),
    MT("Montana"),
    NC("NorthCarolina"),
    ND("NorthDakota"),
    NE("Nebraska"),
    NH("NewHampshire"),
    NJ("NewJersey"),
    NM("NewMexico"),
    NV("Nevada"),
    NY("NewYork"),
    OH("Ohio"),
    OK("Oklahoma"),
    OR("Oregon"),
    PA("Pennsylvania"),
    RI("RhodeIsland"),
    SC("SouthCarolina"),
    SD("SouthDakota"),
    TN("Tennessee"),
    TX("Texas"),
    UT("Utah"),
    VA("Virginia"),
    VT("Vermont"),
    WA("Washington"),
    WI("Wisconsin"),
    WV("WestVirginia"),
    WY("Wyoming")
}
```

Use it as:

```
val alaska = State.valueOf("AK").stateName
val virginia = State.VA.stateName
```