# Proper way to use the same large array in multiple functions without being redundant?

Tags: php, global-variables

I don't have a specific situation I'm dealing with, so consider this more of a general question.  If language is important, answers can tend more toward PHP.

If I have a large array (or other data type) of data which I require in multiple functions, that does not change, how should I use that data?  For example, maybe I have an array that looks like

```
$states = array(
                "AL" => "Alabama",
                     ...
                "WY" => "Wyoming"
                );
```

Obviously, this array won't need to change anytime soon.  If I have five functions that have to use the above array, what is the best solution?  My three ideas are:

- Declare it as a global constant

This one seems the most straightforward, however some people I've talked to seem to recommend shying away from using global variables.  Any insight here would be appreciated.

- Pass it into the function

This one seems like a bad idea to me because it never changes, and function parameters should be for variables, right?  Not to mention having to pass it into a function that doesn't use it, just so it can be used by another function.  That seems like a poor practice.

- Have it be returned by a function

This is one that I haven't seen used a lot, but I've used myself a couple of times for passing mysqli_connect() information to multiple functions.  It worked quite well.  Is this regarded as poor practice?  Should I just suck it up and use a global constant?

I realize that using a global constant sounds obvious, but I've heard (and read) more than one mantra like, "if you're declaring globals, you're doing it wrong" and stuff like that.  Can anyone explain why this might be?

Thanks for any insight that you can give me, guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My general advice would be to build a "service provider" class, which is analogous to your "return it from a function" option. Here are some specific thoughts:

- Declare it as a global constant

First, constants can only be scalar values, so you cannot technically have an "constant" array. Second, what you say is almost always true: globals are a hint that there is a better way (with some exception).

- Pass it into the function

If they are *actually* constant (in the "real world" sense, not the computer-science sense), then you are right, passing to a function should be considered code-clutter (unless the functions should be abstracted from the knowledge of the "global" value, but that's a domain-specific architecture choice.

- Have it be returned by a function

Ding Ding! The reason is essentially this: Anyone can access these to "read", but only the "function" can "write". I put "function" in quotes because it could also be a class or singleton object instance. Basically, you provide a semantically appropriate provider of this *static* information.

One of the benefits of this approach is that you may only need the data quite seldom in a long-running program. The service provider may in that case be written to fetch the values from some out-of-memory persistence and free the memory when it is not needed anymore. Nobody else should need to be responsible for that memory management. Along the same lines, imagine that the project grows and these datum need to be loaded from a database instead of a static array... if you have centralized the access, this is remarkably easy to facilitate and you don't need to have a huge heap of memory lying around for the entire length of your program's execution holding values that are almost never accessed.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer!  When would using globals be appropriate?  Like for mathematical constant or something else?

Comment: The exceptions are highly dependent on the nature of the app and the environment in which it will be deployed. For PHP and most high-level environments like it, it's almost always better to encapsulate the values into a provider. Moving to environments which are "closer to the hardware" starts to bring in considerations of performance trade-off, but this is rarely a concern for PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on NOT using globals (which is indeed a bad habit!) then you can "hide" it inside a function:

```
function get_state($state_code){
  static $states = array(
                "AL" => "Alabama",
                     ...
                "WY" => "Wyoming"
                );
  return $states[$state_code];
}
```

But, in this case, it seems to me that using a global array would be just fine, kind of like creating an Enam in Java.

Comment: Ah, but what if my array were like

Comment: At least declare the array `static` to avoid having it redeclared each time the function is called.

Comment: @enkrypt0r I don't understand your comment. deceze - that's a good idea! I'll update my solution.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter above.  Here's what I meant to say:

Ah, but what if I wanted to perform different operations on the same array?  Perhaps I'd like one function to get the state code from the state name, and another function to get the state name from the state code.  Surely I could do both of these things with the same array, so wouldn't it be a bad idea to have the same array in to different places?

Comment: @enkrypt0r on this specific example you probably wouldn't want to modify the array, not even via. setter. But in general, if you want to be able to do more than just fetching a value for an array, then deceze's answer here will best fit your needs!

Comment: @deceze I advise against the `static` keyword, which will only cause that array to hog memory for the entire life of the execution, no matter how long ago the array was used! Yes there may be some cost to moving it back into useful memory when the function is next called, but given the semantic of that array, I imaging it will be a very small part of an arbitrarily lengthy execution. `static` storage duration should not be confused with `constant` values; an array this big should be moved out of memory as soon as it's useful life is complete.

Comment: @ctrahey A valid point. I guess it depends on how often it is used throughout the app. If it's just read once or twice, setting and unsetting it may be beneficial. If it's used all the time though, I'd still advise using `static`, since often-used values should be kept in memory.

Comment: @ctrahey I agree with deceze: the size of such an array in the memory will be 1-2KB so declaring it as global or static should not effect the performance.

Comment: @alfasin Sure, your call. To me, 1-2 KB *is* significant, and it's even more significant when you treat it casually and end up making similar choices in many places in your app... Someday you'll have to write a long-running program and need to know how and where to properly handle memory. I choose to operate with that kind of scrutiny all the time, because why the hell not, eh? I'm not fond of PHP's reputation for cowboy code, and I think we can do something about it ;-)

Comment: @ctrahey 'Someday you'll have to write a long-running program and need to know how and where to properly handle memory' - let's assume that I  already wrote 'long running programs', and you know what, I'll be damned if I didn't have to do [**that exactly**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005751/is-there-a-util-to-convert-us-state-name-to-state-code-eg-arizona-to-az/11006236#11006236)... and I don't really understand your argument, after all, you agreed with me in your answer - cause if you build a "service provider" you keep the same array in memory throughout the all execution, right ?

Comment: @alfasin I'm sure we're on the same page (+1 btw)('twas the *proverbial* "you" to whom I spoke). And the reason I like your answer (and we are in agreement) is that it affords the program the choice to load the data from elsewhere at the time of access (i.e. "lazy loading") and optionally to discard it from memory. Sorry to hint at an escalation of tone here, that's certainly not my intention. I just sometimes think PHP devs (again, a generalization and not about you) don't fully grasp the difference between `static` (indicates storage duration, still volatile) and `constant` (doesn't change).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a wrapping class would be in order that bundles those functions that are apparently related together:

```
class CountryHelper {

    protected static $states = array('AL' => ..., ...);

    public function foo() {
        self::$states ...
    }

    public function bar() {
        self::$states ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmmm... This seems like a good solution for most problems, but what if I had a small, procedural, single file?  Like a cron job or something?  Would you still recommend a separate class?

Comment: If it's the sanest structure for your code, it doesn't matter how big or small the using script is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the environment you are working in - in MVC, I would inject this as a static property of the Controller so you can access it via:

```
 $this -> settings('states')[$state];
```

Otherwise, I'd just stick with static fields of a `Settings` class:

```
 class Settings
 {

      static $states = array( ... );

 }
```

Or even with a singleton filled up at script startup, that could load settings from elsewhere if needed [yaml / ini] - though singleton using is not a good practice in my opinion.

Anyway don't go global, always namespace your vars / functions properly.

Comment: Note that "MVC", in this sense, would characterize the array in question as a "model", and it should not be a property on the controller, but a separate and distinct model which the controller could choose to load as necessary and pass to whomever it decides needs it. This is actually a decent case-study in the value of MVC; 'cuase doing it wrong means the data is hanging around wether it is used or not, when it should logically be loaded and discarded as needed.