# Java - country / state / district dropdown in application level

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, static

I need to implement drop downs for country, state and district.
For getting a list of state, I don't want to make a query to the DB.
i.e. When the server starts up, all the list of countries, states and districts should be loaded on to the memory using static class or methods. From there I should be able to fetch list of states and list of districts. For example, from one district, I should be able to find out from which state and which country it belongs to.

Every country, state and district, will have an `id`, `title`, `shortcode`.
My prime intention is to reduce the number of query request to the DB serve.

Comment: This one doesn't have the districts - but it covers all US states: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005751/is-there-a-util-to-convert-us-state-name-to-state-code-eg-arizona-to-az/11006236#11006236 Canada has very few provinces (equivalent to states) and I'm not sure if other countries even have this kind of division

Comment: What is the question? Are you expecting someone to post a complete implementation?

Comment: Save them in a suitable context (e.g. `ServletContext`) when your software starts, for example in a `ServletContextListener`?

Comment: is that a web app or a desktop app? if it's a web app, use javascript, if it's desktop, load from a properties file once and keep it in memory in a singleton

Comment: ...and what exactly is the problem you need help with?

Comment: @kharyam If i could get some sample / similar implementations, that would be good.